# Unable to add empty option field with select2 and django

Tags: django, django-models

I am using django select2 for a web application. The function getNames() loads the names from db. The getNames() return a list of tuples in form *[(id_value1,value1),(id_value2,value2)] where id_value is integer and value1 is string* however I want to use a placeholder for the select2 field. The placeholder only appear when the select element has an empty option field i-e 
       < option > < / option >.

The problem is I am unable to add the empty option field. Any idea how can i do that.

```
field = Select2ChoiceField(
    required=False,
    widget=Select2Widget(attrs={'placeholder':"Select your name"}),
    choices=(getNames()),
```

Comment: You can prepend a list with an empty tuple like `choices=[('', '')] + getNames()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. By adding an empty

```
field = Select2ChoiceField(
required=False,
widget=Select2Widget(attrs={'placeholder':"Select your name"}),
choices=getNames())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  

#Replacing the underlined with the one below solved my problem
choices=[('', '')] + getNames())
```

It can also be solved by using jquery in the template. Hope it helps